# avoiding pip trying legacy setup.py install?

Tags: pip

i have been trying to port a python virtualenv to a new M1/silicon machine, and have made lots of progress.  but `llvmlite` was in my requirements.txt file, and it generated these lines:

```
Collecting llvmlite<0.35,>=0.34.0.dev0
Using cached llvmlite-0.34.0.tar.gz (107 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
...
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for llvmlite, since package 'wheel' is not installed.

Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: .../venv/cvsim/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dz/8plg36qs1r50kjb6wvn4dwh00000gn/T/pip-install-v7v_g3dv/llvmlite_767a64436ab24819b5ed6f21d03c1063/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dz/8plg36qs1r50kjb6wvn4dwh00000gn/T/pip-install-v7v_g3dv/llvmlite_767a64436ab24819b5ed6f21d03c1063/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/dz/8plg36qs1r50kjb6wvn4dwh00000gn/T/pip-record-k443gds4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/rik/data/venv/cvsim/include/site/python3.10/llvmlite
     cwd: /private/var/folders/dz/8plg36qs1r50kjb6wvn4dwh00000gn/T/pip-install-v7v_g3dv/llvmlite_767a64436ab24819b5ed6f21d03c1063/
Complete output (29 lines):
running install
running build
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'llvm-config'
```

This `llvmlite` issue seems related to this [known issue](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/693).

but now i've *removed* `llvmlite` from requirements, and it is *still* trying to do the legacy setup.py install.  i can't figure out how/why/where pip is still trying:

```
% python -m pip uninstall llvmlite

        WARNING: Skipping llvmlite as it is not installed.

% python -m pip show llvmlite

        WARNING: Package(s) not found: llvmlite

% python -m pip cache remove llvmlite

        WARNING: No matching packages for pattern "llvmlite"
        Files removed: 0
```

`piptree` doesn't tell me anything either:

```
% pipdeptree | grep llvm
% (crickets)
```

I've seen suggestions that something like `python setup.py uninstall llvmlite` might work, but have avoided old-school setup utils for some time.  Thanks for any suggestions as to how to remove this dependency?

EDIT: `requirements.txt` posted as requested:

```
alabaster
alembic
appnope
argon2-cffi
async-generator
attrs
Babel
backcall
bleach
bokeh
boto3
botocore
certifi
cffi
chardet
click
cliff
cloudpickle
cma
cmaes
cmd2
colorama
colorlog
country-converter
covasim
cycler
dask
decorator
defusedxml
dill
distributed
docutils
dominate
entrypoints
et-xmlfile
feather-format
Flask
Flask-Bootstrap
gitdb
GitPython
HeapDict
idna
imagesize
iniconfig
ipykernel
ipython
ipython-genutils
ipywidgets
itsdangerous
jabbar
jdcal
jedi
jellyfish
Jinja2
jmespath
joblib
jsonpickle
jsonschema
jupyter
jupyter-client
jupyter-console
jupyter-core
jupyterlab-pygments
jupyterlab-widgets
kaleido
kiwisolver
# llvmlite
Mako
MarkupSafe
matplotlib
mistune
msgpack
multiprocess
nbclient
nbconvert
nbformat
nbsphinx
nest-asyncio
notebook
# numba 
numexpr
numpy
openpyexcel
optuna
packaging
pandas 
pandoc
pandocfilters
parso
patsy
pbr
pexpect
pickleshare
Pillow
plantweb
plotly
pluggy
plumbum
ply
pockets
prettytable
prometheus-client
prompt-toolkit
psutil
ptyprocess
py
pyabc
pyarrow 
pycountry
pycparser
Pygments
pypandoc
pyparsing
pyperclip
pyrsistent
pytest
python-dateutil
python-editor
pytz
PyYAML
pyzmq
qtconsole
QtPy
redis
requests
s3transfer
scikit-learn
scipy
sciris
Send2Trash
six
sklearn
smmap
snowballstemmer
sortedcontainers
Sphinx
sphinx-rtd-theme
sphinxcontrib-applehelp
sphinxcontrib-devhelp
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp
sphinxcontrib-jsmath
sphinxcontrib-napoleon
sphinxcontrib-qthelp
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml
SQLAlchemy
statsmodels 
stevedore
# tables
tblib
tenacity
terminado
testpath
threadpoolctl
toml
toolz
tornado
tqdm
traitlets
# tumor2d
typing-extensions
urllib3
visitor
watermark
wcwidth
webencodings
Werkzeug
widgetsnbextension
xlrd
XlsxWriter
zict
```

Comment: share your requirements.txt -- we can't really help beyond guessing popular packages that depend on llvmlite (`numba`?)

Comment: Thanks @AnthonySottile.  i had guessed `numba` also and removed that; no change.  i can try to add the requirements.txt file to my OP, but are we really reduced to trying to *guess*?!

Comment: without information provided noone can reproduce your problem so yeah one would have to guess at the solution

Comment: @AnthonySottile ok, i've added the file.

Comment: covasim -> numba -> llvmlite

Comment: wow, and how did you find this (so quick!) please?

Comment: installed everything and looked at the dependencies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240319/discussion-between-rikb-and-anthony-sottile).